# Xcode, text field for selected button state not saving value entered

Tags: ios, xcode

I am sure that this is a really easy solution for someone with IOS experience. My problem is as follows, (forgive me if my terminology in explaining the situation is poor)

I want to change the selected state of my text to be the  character instead of the word Ace.

Initially the selected state is set to show "Ace" on the button as shown in the picture below.

[image: Initial Setting]

I then paste in the appropriate  character as shown in the picture below

[image: Changed Setting]

However, when I do a command save, then toggle the button pointed to in the picture below back and forth from default to selected the text field reverts back to Ace instead of being  as I want it.

[image: Final Frustrating Result]

Forgive me if this is really easy, but I can seem to figure it out. As I said, I have tried command save after changing it, but that is not working, I can't really think of anything else to try, and googling this answer is difficult as I am not sure how to even word the question without visually describing my problem as I have done here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I just solved this right after I posted the question

All you have to do is click outside of the text field where you enter what you want the state to be and it saves it. Can't believe my headache was so simple...